# Looping through pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, date, sliding

Dataframe:

```
       date      A    B    C    D
index
0      2015-01   ..   ..   ..   ..
1      2015-01   ..   ..   ..   ..
2      2015-02   ..   ..   ..   ..
3      2015-02   ..   ..   ..   ..
4      2015-03   ..   ..   ..   ..
5      2015-03   ..   ..   ..   ..
6      2015-04   ..   ..   ..   ..
7      2015-04   ..   ..   ..   ..
8      2015-05   ..   ..   ..   ..
9      2015-05   ..   ..   ..   ..
...
1000   ...       ..   ..   ..   ..
```

I want to iterate using the date (pd.to_datetime) starting with a fixed window (e.g., first three months [2015-01, 2015-01, 2015-02, 2015-02, 2015-03, 2015-03]) and returning a dataframe:

```
       date      A    B    C    D
index
0      2015-01   ..   ..   ..   ..
1      2015-01   ..   ..   ..   ..
2      2015-02   ..   ..   ..   ..
3      2015-02   ..   ..   ..   ..
4      2015-03   ..   ..   ..   ..
5      2015-03   ..   ..   ..   ..
```

Then adding the next month [2015-04, 2015-04] and dropping the oldest one [2015-01, 2015-01], returning the next dataframe:

```
       date      A    B    C    D
index
2      2015-02   ..   ..   ..   ..
3      2015-02   ..   ..   ..   ..
4      2015-03   ..   ..   ..   ..
5      2015-03   ..   ..   ..   ..
6      2015-04   ..   ..   ..   ..
7      2015-04   ..   ..   ..   ..
```

Continuing this until end of data.

I have figured out the following code:

```
periods = len(dataframe)
fxw = 3

for i in range(0, periods):
    start = i                       
    if i + fxw > periods:              
       break
    else: end_df = i + fxw
 
# output:
 
# df1
       date      A    B    C    D
index
0      2015-01   ..   ..   ..   ..
1      2015-01   ..   ..   ..   ..
2      2015-02   ..   ..   ..   ..

# df2
       date      A    B    C    D
index
3      2015-02   ..   ..   ..   ..
4      2015-03   ..   ..   ..   ..
5      2015-03   ..   ..   ..   ..
 
...
# dfend
```

Where I can set a fixed window (fxw = 3) to iterate over the length of the dataframe 3 rows at time until end of data. (e.g., if dataframe has 12 rows, it will return 4 dataframes of 3 rows each). In this way, however, neither I am selecting the window by date nor I am dropping the last datapoint and adding the next one. I have not figured out how to do so yet. If anyone has a possible solution/suggestion, it would be very appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: Both `pd.Period()` and `pd.PeriodIndex()` would be useful for making this 3-month sliding window; see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html

Comment: This sounds interesting, thanks I will have a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.  Start by building a data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

date = [ f'2015-{i:02d}' for i in range(1, 7) ]
date = np.repeat(date, 2)
date = [pd.Period(d) for d in date]

n = len(date)
amt = [10 * i for i in range(n)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'amt': amt})

print(df.head())
```

Next, construct a period range, using the min and max dates from the data frame:

```
period_range = pd.period_range(start=df['date'].min(), 
                               end=df['date'].max(), 
                               freq='M')
```

Now, iterate over the data frame:

```
months_in_window = 2

for start, end in zip(period_range, period_range[months_in_window - 1: ]):
    mask = (start <= df['date']) & (df['date'] <= end)
    print(df[mask], end='\n\n')

      date  amt
0  2015-01    0
1  2015-01   10
2  2015-02   20
3  2015-02   30

      date  amt
2  2015-02   20
3  2015-02   30
4  2015-03   40
5  2015-03   50

<rest of output omitted to save space>
```

You can often use pandas tools (including `groupby` and `rolling`) to avoid iterating over a data frame.

UPDATE:

We can control both length of a window, and time from start of one window to start of next:

```
# create list of periods
periods = pd.period_range(start='2020-01-01', periods=24, freq='M')

# create parameters
months_in_window = 3   # start of window i to end of window i
step = 5               # start of window i to start of window i+1

# create start and end points for each window
windows = [
    (start, end)
    for start, end 
        in zip(periods[::step], periods[window_size-1::step])
]

for w in windows: print(w)

(Period('2020-01', 'M'), Period('2020-03', 'M'))
(Period('2020-06', 'M'), Period('2020-08', 'M'))
(Period('2020-11', 'M'), Period('2021-01', 'M'))
(Period('2021-04', 'M'), Period('2021-06', 'M'))
(Period('2021-09', 'M'), Period('2021-11', 'M'))
```

Finally, iterating one the data frame looks like this (no change to mask):

```
for start, end in windows:
    mask = (start <= df['date']) & (df['date'] <= end)
    print(df[mask], end='\n\n')
```

Comment: Hi @jsmart, I very much like your method, very clear and useful, thanks!

Comment: I have one last question: let's say I set **months_in_window = 15** so it will return **2015-01 ... 2016-03** and then will **drop/add** 1 month in loop. If I want to **drop/add more than 1 month** (for example, lets say 3 months), such as: df1 will be **2015-01 ... 2016-03**, then df2 will be **2015-04 ... 2016-06**, then df3 will be **2015-07 ... 2016-09**, etc... . Is there a way to do it? I guess we ll have to make some changes on --> **mask = (start <= df['date']) & (df['date'] <= end)**. If you have an idea on how to do it, please let me know and thank you!

Comment: This version has `months_in_window = 2` -- so each window has 2 months in it Jan+Feb; Feb+March; March+April; ....  Just change `months_in_window` to 3, and you'll get Jan+Feb+March; Feb+March+April; ...  Also, you could print `start` and `end` in the for loop to show this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I perfectly understand that by changing **monts_in_window** you can fix the number of months as you like. However, whatever window size we choose, the loop will **drop and add just 1 month on each new df. Hence, my question now is, if I set **monts_in_window = 5** which is Jan+Feb+Mar+Apr+May, then with this version the next df will be Feb+Mar+Apr+May-Jun. But if I want it to be Mar+Apr+May+July+Jul, therefore **dropping and adding 2 months at time (and not just 1)** , would that be possible by modifying your version?

Comment: And this is why I have mentioned we might do some change on --> **mask = (start <= df['date']) & (df['date'] <= end)** to achieve my desired result. Thanks for your help and I hope I was clear enough :)

Comment: `zip()` in the update above controls both size of a window, and spacing between start of consecutive windows.

Comment: this is more than perfect! super clear and easy customisable, very well done to you and very much appreciated your effort!

Comment: Hi! I am trying to understand the logic of **zip(periods[::step], periods[window_size-1::step])**. As for **periods[::step]**, is it correct to say that for starting we jump by 'step' and then ending on last datapoint of dataframe? And for **periods[window_size-1::step]** how do you interpret it? Thanks!

Comment: Let's start with `zip(XS, YS)` where XS and YS are iterables (not necessarily the same length).  In this case, zip produces a sequence of tuples (e.g., (x[0], y[0]), (x[1], y[1]), ...  And the sequence ends (zip terminates) when the shortest iterable is exhausted.  Here's a short example in code:  `ns = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; for x, y in zip(ns, ns[1:]): print(x, y)`.  The key is to understand how zip works in this case.  Does that help?

Comment: Okay, I have got it now, this: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip was super useful for understanding !

Comment: I have a more advanced question if I might ask: taking as example the above example with months_in_window = 3 and step = 5, let's say for each new window that comes in loop, I will perform a function on it. If I want to **measure the respective length in percentage** between the 3 months in window and the 5 step (which are 5 months) over the full size of the window (which obviously will be of 8 months), and pass this percentage to a variable (which will then be passed to the function that I perform on each window), is there a way to automate this on each window in zip()?

Comment: I have also made this question as a new question available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63230518/sliding-windows-measuring-length-of-observations-on-each-looped-window  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correclty, you want to loop over the dataframe and get a chunk of 4 rows at each time. You can try something like this and adjust as you like:

first sort the dataframe by date. For this you can use the `sort_values` function:

```
df = your_df.sort_values(by='date')
```

notice if your date column not in the right datetime format, then you need to do that before sorting:

```
your_df['date'] =pd.to_datetime(your_df.date)
```

then you can use the for loop

```
for i in range(0, len(df), 4): # the 4 here means return a chunk of 4 rows
    chunk = df.iloc[i:i+4, :]
    print(chunk)
    # do your magic
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I get your method which works fine if you want to select your data by rows and iterate through the length. However, I would like to use a similar approach but rather selecting the date (months) and iterating through the dataframe length (e.g., fixed windows Jan, Feb, March, and then dropping Jan and adding Apr, etc.. untill end of dataframe). Any suggestion on how to customise your sample with date selection? thanks you!

Comment: so you want to sort the df by datetime column and then iterate over it and get a chunk?

Comment: Okay sorry but I was not super clear. What you have proposed is to sort the dataframe by date (which is already sorted correctly, hence we do not need it) and then do the for loop selecting a number of rows (4 in your example). Thansk but however, is not what I am looking

Comment: I want to select the date (rather than the rows) and iterate through all values of the date chosen. And then, doing a sliding window dropping 1 date (e.g., oldest month) and adding another data (e.g., next month)