# Sliding windows - measuring length of observations on each looped window

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, zip, sliding-window

Let's analyse this sample code where [zip()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/zip) is used to create different windows from a dataset and return them in loop.

```
months = [Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May]

for x, y in zip(months, months[1:]):
    print(x, y)

# Output of each window will be:
Jan Feb 
Feb Mar
Mar Apr
Apr May
```

Let's suppose that now I want to **calculate the respective length percentage** between the months used in each window.

Example in steps:

1. When returning the first window (Jan Feb), I want to calculate the % length of Jan over the full window (which equals to Jan + Feb) and return it a new variable
2. When returning the second window (Feb Mar), I want to calculate the % length of Feb over the full window (which equals to Feb + Mar) and return it a new variable
3. Continuing this process until last window

Any suggestions on how I might implement this idea in the for loop are welcome!

Thank you!

**EDIT**

```
months = [Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May]

for x, y in zip(months, months[2:]):
    print(x, y)

# Output of each window will be:
Jan Feb March
Feb Mar Apr
Mar Apr May
```

The goal is to calculate the length of two months on each window over the full window length:

- 1st window: Jan + Feb / Jan + Feb + March
- 2nd window: Feb + Mar / Feb + Mar + Apr
- continuing to last window

We can now calculate one month over the size of each window **(with start.month)**. However, how do we adapt this to include more than one month?

Also, instead of using **days_in_month**, would there be a way to use the length of the datapoints (rows) in each month?

By using length of datapoints (rows) I mean that each month has many datapoints in 'time' format (e.g., 60 mins format). This would imply that 1 day in a month would have 24 different datapoints (rows).
Example:

```
                         column
rows             
01-Jan-2010 T00:00        value
01-Jan-2010 T01:00        value
01-Jan-2010 T02:00        value
...                       ...
01-Jan-2010 T24:00        value
02-Jan-2010 T00:00        value
...                       ...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way.  (In my case, `months` is a `period_range` object.)

```
import pandas as pd
months = pd.period_range(start='2020-01', periods=5, freq='M')
```

Now, iterate over range.  Each iteration is a two-month window.

```
# print header labels
print('{:10s} {:10s} {:>10s} {:>10s} {:>10s} {:>10s} '.format(
    'start', 'end', 'month', 'front (d)', 'total (d)', 'frac'))

for start, end in zip(months, months[1:]):
    front_month = start.month

    # number of days in first month (e.g., Jan)
    front_month_days = start.days_in_month

    # number of days in current sliding window (e.g., Jan + Feb)
    days_in_curr_window = (end.end_time - start.start_time).days

    frac = front_month_days / days_in_curr_window

    print('{:10s} {:10s} {:10d} {:10d} {:10d} {:10.3f}'.format(
        str(start), str(end), front_month,
        front_month_days, days_in_curr_window, frac))


start      end             month  front (d)  total (d)       frac 
2020-01    2020-02             1         31         60      0.517
2020-02    2020-03             2         29         60      0.483
2020-03    2020-04             3         31         61      0.508
2020-04    2020-05             4         30         61      0.492
```

Comment: Thank you! okay this works smoothly and it is very clear, well done! Now, if I set each window with **three months** (so it will be Jan - Mar... Feb - Apr... Mar - May) and I want to calculate not 1 but **the first two months** over the full window (hence, Jan + Feb / Jan + Feb + Mar), I guess there should be a way to set **front_month** as the first 2 months and not only as start.month, right?

Comment: In addition, I have noticed something: if we use a date format of only **'Year-Month'**, where do the days come from when making the calculation? is it a feature included in **pd.period_range**? if instead of using the days to calculate the length of each month we want to use the actual data points (i.e., row numbers), would that be possible somehow?

Comment: `pd.Period` represents a period of time.  Helpful attributes include: `start_time`, `end_time`, and `days_in_month`.  Details here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Period.html

Comment: Please can you post sample input and output data for 'using the actual data points (row numbers)'?  Not sure what the goal is.

Comment: Thank you for replying back! I have edited the question, hope it is clear now:)

Comment: I might have figured out a possible solution **if we want to calculate the % of the last three months over the full window** : by taking as example your code above, if I change **periods=12** and **zip(months, months[11:])**, I would now get a single window: 2020-01 to 2020-12. Then, if I will add **end_q = end.qyear**, the outcome that will print will be **2020** (I guess it refers to 2020-10 + 2020-11 + 2020-12). Now, do you think is there a way to calculate the size (e.g., in days) of end_q? I have tried with **days_in_month**, but it did not work as expected.

Comment: Because if we can actually calculate how many days (or how many datapoints (i.e., rows)) are in **end_q** (which is given by **qyear** that is an attribute of **pd.Period**), then I will just do: end_q  /  full window (which in your code is given by **days_in_curr_window**) and the result will be my desired outcome :)

Comment: Based on the method you provided, I have made a new question with achieved outcome and desired outcome here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267605/pandas-period-measuring-period-percentage

Comment: I will mark this question as completed! Hope the new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267605/pandas-period-measuring-period-percentage) would be clear now, and if you still have some time to have a look that would be great! and thank you so much for the time and effort you have invested in answering these questions so far, they have been very useful!